# python openpyxl ubicar un valor sin saber su ubicacion

Tags: python, excel

estoy haciendo un sistema para guardar mis contraseñas en excel, tengo todo el sistema hecho por lo que no necesito poner el codigo sobre eso pero por ejemplo mi programa te pregunta que quieres hacer, si eliges la opcion 2(obtener el sitio) te da un input

Si usas sheet[FILAYCOLUMNA].value te da el valor de esa fila y columna especifica pero el usuario obviamente no tiene idea de eso, entonces quiero que si esta escrito unity con el input lo obtenga

```
sitio = input("Escribe el nombre del sitio que buscas>> ") #RESPUESTA DEL USUARIO: unity
sheet[sitio].value

print(f"unity se encuentra en {FILAcolumna}")
```

se que el sheet[sitio].value no tiene sentido ni significa nada pero me doy a entender, quiero que busque en excel donde esta ubicado ese input que es unity por ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Recorre las columnas en busca del valor

Comment: Una planilla no es más que una forma avanzada de un archivo de acceso secuencial, como dice Christian, tienes que recorrer mediante un ciclo todas las celdas de la columna A hasta encontrar la cadena del sitio a buscar, con la fila ya sabes que en la segunda columna tendrás esa contraseña.

Comment: hola, puedes darme una idea de como hacerlo porfavor?

Comment: si te diriges a alguien en particular es preferible mencionarlo, si puedo te daré un ejemplo

Comment: gracias, que ejemplo

Comment: lo siento, también tengo cosas que hacer y es domingo. Ahí tienes tu respuesta

Answer (score 0):

He cambiado los valores del archivo Excel, pero eso no tiene nada que ver. Teniendo un Excel de esta forma.

[image: Archivo excel]

Simplemente tenemos que recorrer la primera columna, esto lo hacemos con un simple siclo `for` que itere en la columna `A`.

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook

#cargamos el archivo
wb = load_workbook('ejemplo.xlsx') 
sheet = wb['Sheet1'] #cargamos la hoja

#pedimos un dato al usuario
entrada = input("sitio a buscar: ")

for cell in sheet["A"]:
    if cell.value == entrada:
        print(cell.value, sheet[f"B{cell.row}"].value)
```

Al tener nuestra hoja ya cargada podemos indicarle una columna en específico para hacer cualquier operación, al hacer un `for` nos devolverá un objeto `Cell` del cual ya podemos extraer sus propiedades como `value`. Dentro del ciclo se comprueba si el valor de la celda es igual a lo introducido por el usuario, en caso sea así se le muestra el nombre del sitio y la contraseña. Como la contraseña está en la columna posterior (columna `B`) entonces solo accedemos a la propiedad `row` de `cell` que nos devuelve la fila en la que estamos, por lo que usamos *f-strings* para concatenar y extraer su valor.